# Mic on skype doesnt work well at all

Tags: skype, microphone

I was using skype and I had gotten a new computer which I now use to play on. Skype then decides to add a static to the call. This then results in my friends moaning at me, if I boost my mic then more static comes but if I lower my mic my friends cant hear me, please help as this is urgent and has been going on for weeks!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running windows 7/8/10. There should be a program called Sound Recorder

[image]

The program is very basic. Hit the **Start Recording** button. Talk for about 1 minute about anything and Stop Recording. Then it will tell you to save a Untitled.wma file somewhere. Pick the desktop. Play this file with any media player.

How does it sound? If it sounds terrible. Then you know what the problem is. 
If it sounds fine. Then the problem might be with your installation of skype. Maybe try to re-install it. Or it could be possible you just have a bad internet connection and the audio being transferred through skype is being altered somehow.

Another Suggestion would be to go out and buy a new microphone. temporarily use that instead of whatever you're using now, and see if that doesn't fix the problem.

The point is... isolate the problem, then work the problem.